# Sidekiq is queueing mails in the 'default' queue instead of 'mailers' queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sidekiq, rails-activejob, ruby-on-rails-7

While upgrading my Rails 6.0 application to Rails 7.0.3, I'm facing the following problem :

Sidekiq is enqueueing all my mailer jobs through the `default` queue instead of the `mailers` queue like it used to before.

Code related to the same :

in application.rb :

```
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

My mailer :

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def staff_welcome(user, password)
    @user = user
    @password = password
    mail(to: user.email, from: "DummyName <#{APP_CONFIG[:notifications_email]}>", reply_to: "#{APP_CONFIG[:outbound_email]}", subject: "Your staff account has been created")
  end
```

And then, inside the controller, i'm calling the mailer as follows :

```
def create
    @user = User.new
    @user.attributes = users_params.merge(state: 'active', source: :dummy_source, activity: 1)

    set_roles(users_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        if @user.staff?
          UserMailer.staff_welcome(@user, params[:user][:password]).deliver_later
```

I'm interested in finding out why upon upgrading to Rails 7 is my queue for mailers changing? When i run the server with Rails 6, the mailers get queued via the `mailers` queue, but with Rails 7, the queue is `default`.

I understand that if i call the mailer from inside an ActiveJob, and inside the controller call the job instead of the mailer directly, I will be able to use syntax like `queue_as :mailers`. Is that the correct way to fix this?

I checked the changelog for sidekiq but couldn't find anything related to this? Did they change the default queue when it comes to mailers?

Also, can i set sidekiq_options with the `deliver_later` function?

Comment: First, check whether your config `config.action_mailer.deliver_later_queue_name` be changed or not (by default it's `:mailers`). Second, check whether your sidekiq config declared that mail queue or not.

Comment: In rails 6.1 it is changed from `mailers` to job adapter's default - [refer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/actionmailer/CHANGELOG.md#rails-610-december-09-2020)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 6.1, they changed the default queue name.

More info on the change here: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40766

In the Sidekiq documentation:
https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job#queues